# If $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are distinct monic polynomials they cannot be associates.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are distinct monic polynomials they cannot be associates.

So if they are associates then they would be multiples of one another, thus $a(x) \neq c \cdot b(x)$ for some $c\in F$, where $F$ is our field. Being monic means that the leading coefficient of the polynomials is 1. I think this is saying that these two polynomials has no common divisors, thus their gcd=1. Is there anything that says associates have to have a certain gcd to help me prove this or am I even moving the correct direction?

Comment: $a(x) = c \, b(x) $ iff $\frac{a(x)}{A} = \frac{b(x)}{B}$ where $A,B$ are the coefficients of higher degree.

Answer (score 0):

If they were associates, the polynomials would have the same degree ($c\in F\setminus\{0\}$) and the constant would have to be $1$ as their leading terms agree. But $a$ and $b$ are distinct polynomials so this is a contradiction.

Comment: This may be a dumb question but does being distinct imply that they do not have the same degree? I thought it meant they did not share common factors?

Answer (score 0):

If $b(x)$ is a monic polynomial, then the leading coefficient of $cb(x)$ is $c$. Thus if $a(x)=cb(x)$ and $a(x)$ is also monic, we have $c=1$. Therefore $a(x)=b(x)$.